# Why does the same RGB value appear different between Interface Builder and Photoshop?

Tags: iphone, colors, interface-builder

I have a `UIImageView` that I've pointed to a PNG who's background is `RGB(240,240,240)`. I've then set the parent UIView's background to the same colour in Interface Builder.

You'll notice that they are slightly different. When I take a screenshot and re-examine, I see that the UIView's background in IB is not `RGB(240,240,240)`, but `RGB(236,236,236)`.

Why is this??

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Mine are the same. Maybe it's your Photoshop's setting issue. Check out the `Image`->`Mode`, what is it?

Comment: Photoshop may be applying a color correction based on your monitor calibration or some other voodoo.

Comment: Yeah check the profile settings in Photoshop. Also how are you saving out of Photoshop? Save for Web?

Comment: @MarkRansom @steveax : I just found that it cannot be the photoshop's problem, as the image's rgb value is correct, what's incorrect is the background of the `UIImageView`. @barfoon, have you tried to create a new imageView and reset the background & image to it? Setting the alhpa of imageView's background color will make difference.

Comment: @KJuly - I don't have the background set on the `UIImageView`. It's a `UIImageView` that is pointed to an image (PNG), who's background is set to be that colour. The `UIView`'s background colour has been set to match, and they don't appear the same.

Comment: Can you put the image up somewhere I can download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a manufacturer specific monitor driver installed?  Have a look at the monitor profile.  Its probably different from the colour profile in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

I had to tweak the numbers I used in IB to get my colors to match.

For example: You want (240,240,240) and it gives you (236,236,236) dispite that you entered (240,240,240).

I entered (244,244,244) and it gave me a color closer to (240,240,240).  I figured if I entered 240 and it gave me 236, then I should add 4 to my original colour code.

I had to do this a couple of times to get the right number.

Not an elegant solution but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

RGB value is meaningless without knowing the colorspace. Make sure you choose "Generic RGB" colorspace when selecting the color using the RGB sliders in Interface Builder.